# Can someone boost even more my code?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @Roman, I've included here all my code.

I'm using just bult-in function and compile to boost my code, but I think that it can be better. My code looks like

```
    nof = 30;
    << NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`;
        gqx = GaussianQuadratureWeights[nof, 0, a]; gqy = 
         GaussianQuadratureWeights[nof, 0, b];
        xi = gqx[[All, 1]]; yi = gqy[[All, 1]]; wix = gqx[[All, 2]]; wiy = 
         gqy[[All, 2]];
        nM = 10; nN = 10;
        dim = nM*nN;
        mVec = Range[1, nM];
        nVec = Range[1, nN];
        weigth = Flatten@KroneckerProduct[{wix}, {wiy}];
        D11[x_,y_] = 115.2 - 1.39201 Cos[1.37428 x] - 30.1568 Cos[2.19884 x] - 
     0.0166422 Cos[2.74855 x] + 13.0219 Cos[3.57312 x] - 
     9.85381 Cos[4.39768 x] - 6.94062 Cos[7.14623 x] - 
     3.20871 Cos[8.79536 x] - 1.44146 Sin[1.37428 x] + 
     67.7332 Sin[2.19884 x] + 0.476569 Sin[2.74855 x] - 
     35.7775 Sin[3.57312 x] - 27.0025 Sin[4.39768 x] - 
     5.82387 Sin[7.14623 x] - 0.920082 Sin[8.79536 x];   
        mat1 = Flatten@
            Table[(2 π^4)/a^4 D11[x, y], {x, xi}, {y, 
              yi}]; // RepeatedTiming

        mat2 = Compile[{{x1, _Real, 1}, {y1, _Real, 1}, {m1, _Real, 
               1}, {n1, _Real, 1}, {p1, _Real, 1}, {q1, _Real, 
               1}, {a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {nof, _Integer}}, 
             Partition[
              Flatten@Table[
                m^2 p^2 Sin[(m π x)/a] Sin[(p π x)/a] Sin[(n π y)/
                  b] Sin[(q π y)/b], {m, m1}, {n, n1}, {p, p1}, {q, 
                 q1}, {x, x1}, {y, y1}], nof^2], Parallelization -> True, 
             RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}][xi, yi, mVec, nVec, mVec, nVec, 
            a, b, nof]; // RepeatedTiming

        mat3 = Compile[{{u, _Real, 1}, {v, _Real, 1}}, u v, 
             RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True][mat2, 
            mat1]; // RepeatedTiming

        D11Mat = Compile[{{mat1, _Real, 2}, {mat2, _Real, 1}, {dim, _Integer}},
             Partition[mat1.mat2, dim],
             Parallelization -> True,
             RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}][mat3, weigth, 
            dim]; // RepeatedTiming

        D11Mat = Partition[mat3.weigth, dim]; // RepeatedTiming
```

Running it, I got the following computing time

> {0.035, Null}
>
> {1.80, Null}
>
> {0.028, Null}
>
> {0.0032, Null}
>
> {0.0027, Null}

It can be seen that `mat2` is the bottleneck of my code. As I need to perform that computation over 600-1000 times, any small time saving on it will be great.

P.S.: `D11[x,y]` varies in each loop, so I cannot solve it analytically.

Comment: @andre314, sorry I'll update it.

Comment: Can you provide examples for `xi` and `yi`?

Comment: Generally, if you can, you should try to put all the definitions inside the code block so that people can simply copy the entire code block, paste it into Mathematica, and run it. I can't seem to get your code to run in 1.80 seconds even when I define `xi` and `yi`.

Comment: It was a mistake, @MassDefect. I'm going to update. Can you try to run now?

Comment: Are you going to be summing over the resulting matrix elements somehow? If yes, then a more direct approach via discrete sine transform may be appropriate.

Comment: I am going to multiply by a vector and then a dot product, @Roman. What direct approach would be it?

Comment: It works now, thanks.

Comment: Maybe include the multiplication by a vector and the dot product in your code, so that people can try to optimize the whole process.

Comment: I'm going to do that. Thank you for that advice, @Roman.

Comment: How come that after this long discussion this code is still not self-contained? What are `GaussianQuadratureWeights`, `a`, and `b`? Maybe you meant two define `D11[x_, y_] =` instead of `D11[x, y] =`...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, `GaussianQuadratureWeights` are Gaussian points to perform a numerical integration. `a` and `b` are dimensions of my problem. Yes, it is `D11[x_,y_]`.

Comment: Once again: Why can't we just copy the code from here and run it in _Mathematica_? You are seeking for help, right? So it is in your own interest to make it as easy to help you as possible. One cannot speed up code in a reliable way without running it. And concrete dimensions of the problem _are_  important as well as definitions for each other symbol that appears in the code.

Comment: A thousand apologies, @HenrikSchumacher. I forgot the most important thing: load the package. `<< NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`;`. So sorry, again. I really appreciate if you yet can help me. I update the Mathematica block.

Comment: A stupid and perhaps irrelevant comment: why don't you try to compile with C target?

Comment: @DarioRosa, I got the half time. Good one!

Comment: Is `D11` always independent of `y`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, no, unfortunately.

Comment: Using `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`,  `CompilationTarget -> "C"` shave quite some in `mat2`, if to compile it first and then test `mat2[xi, yi, mVec, nVec, mVec, nVec, a, b, nof]; // RepeatedTiming`

Comment: @Andrew, the ordering matter of these options? When I try what you recommend, my laptop stuck.

Comment: Idk, for `CompilationTarget -> "C"` to work some C compiler (which WM should recognize) must be installed in the system.

Comment: @Andrew, I have gcc installed in my laptop. This is weird because I've used `CompilationTarget -> "C"` before and it works. Did you try to run on your machine?

Comment: Yes, Win 7, Mma 11.3.

Comment: @Andrew, I've restarted my laptop and it worked. Restarting is always the best first attempt to troubleshoot the machine =). Regarding computing, on my laptop, I got 0.11 s to compile + 0.48 s to execute. It seems to be better to compile and run at the same time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Exploitation of low rank structure

The ordering of summation/dot products is crucial here. As [aooiiii](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/68990/aooiiii) pointed out, `mat2` has a low-rank tensor product structure. So by changing the order of summation/dotting operations, we can make sure that this beast is never assembled explicitly. A good rule of thumb is to sum intermediate results as early as possible. This reduces the number of flops and, often more importantly, the amount of memory that has to be shoved around by the machine. As a simple example consider the sum over all entries of the outer product of two vector `x = {x1,x2,x3}` and `y = {y1,y2,y3}`: First forming the outer product requires $9 = 3 \times 3$ multiplications and summing all entries requires $8 = 3 \times 3 -1$ additions.

```
 Total[KroneckerProduct[x, y], 2]
```

> x1 y1 + x2 y1 + x3 y1 + x1 y2 + x2 y2 + x3 y2 + x1 y3 + x2 y3 + x3 y3

However first summing the vectors and then multiplying requires only $4 = 2 \times (3-1)$ additions and one multiplication:

```
 Total[x] Total[y]
```

> (x1 + x2 + x3) (y1 + y2 + y3)

For vectors of length $n$, this would be $2 n^2 -1$ floating point operations in the first case vs. $2 (n -1) +1$ in the second case. Moreover, the intermediate matrix requires $n^2$ additional units of memory while storing $x$ and $y$ can be done with only $2 n$ units of memory.

Side note: In the "old days" before FMA (fused multiply-add)  instructions took over, CPUs had separate circuits for addition and multiplication. On such machines, multiplication was more expensive than addition and thus this optimization is particularly striking. (My current computer, a Haswell (2014), has still a pure addition circuit, so those days are not that old...)

## Code

Further speed-up can be obtained by using [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496) throughout and by replacing all occurrences of `Table` in high-level code either by vectorized operations or compiled code.

This part of the code needs to be executed only once:

```
Needs["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
nof = 30;
a = 1.;
b = 1.;
{xi, wix} = Transpose[Developer`ToPackedArray[GaussianQuadratureWeights[nof, 0, a]]];
{yi, wiy} = Transpose[Developer`ToPackedArray[GaussianQuadratureWeights[nof, 0, b]]];

First@RepeatedTiming[
  Module[{m = N[mVec], n = N[nVec], u, v},
    u = Sin[KroneckerProduct[xi, m (N[Pi]/a)]].DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[m^2]];
    v = Sin[KroneckerProduct[yi, n (N[Pi]/b)]];
    U = Transpose[MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {u, wix u}], {3, 1, 2}];
    V = MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {wiy v, v}];
    ];
  ]
```

> 0.000164

This part of the code has to be evaluated whenever `D11` changes:

```
First@RepeatedTiming[

  cf = Block[{i},
    With[{code = D11[x,y] /. y -> Compile`GetElement[Y, i]},
     Compile[{{x, _Real}, {Y, _Real, 1}},
      Table[code, {i, 1, Length[Y]}],
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True,
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
      ]
     ]
    ];

  result = ArrayReshape[
    Transpose[
     Dot[U, (2. π^4/a^4 ) cf[xi, yi], V],
     {1, 3, 2, 4}
     ],
    {dim, dim}
    ];

  ]
```

> 0.00065

On my systen, roughly 40% of this timing are due to compilation of `cf`. Notice that the first argument of `cf` is a scalar, so inserting a *vector* (or any other rectangular array) as in `cf[xi, yi]` will call `cf` in a threadable way (using OpenMP parallelization IRRC). *This* is the sole purpose of the option `Parallelization -> True`; `Parallelization -> True` does nothing without `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` or if `cf` is not called in such a threadable way. From what OP told me, it became clear that the function `D11` changes frequently, so `cf` had to be compiled quite often. This is why compiling to C is *not* a good idea (the C-compiler needs much more time),

Finally, checking the relative error of result:

```
Max[Abs[D11Mat - result]]/Max[Abs[D11Mat]]
```

> 4.95633*10^-16

## Explanation attempt

Well, the code might look mysterious, so I try to explain how I wrote it. Maybe that will help OP or others next time when they stumble into a similar problem.

The main problem here is this beast, which is the `Flatten`ing of a tensor of rank $6$:

```
W = Flatten@ Table[
 m^2 p^2 Sin[(m π x)/a] Sin[(p π x)/ a] Sin[(n π y)/b] Sin[(q π y)/b],
 {m, mVec}, {n, nVec}, {p, mVec}, {q, nVec}, {x, xi}, {y, yi}
 ];
```

The first step is to observe that the indices `m`, `p`, and `x` "belong together"; likewise we put `n`, `q` and `y` into a group. Now we can write `W` as an outer product of the following two arrays:

```
W1 = Table[ 
  m^2 p^2 Sin[(m π x)/a] Sin[(p π x)/a], 
  {m, mVec}, {p, mVec}, {x, xi}
  ];
W2 = Table[
  Sin[(n π y)/b] Sin[(q π y)/b], 
  {n, nVec}, {q, nVec}, {y, yi}
  ];
```

Check:

```
Max[Abs[W - Flatten[KroneckerProduct[W1, W2]]]]
```

> 2.84217*10^-14

Next observation: Up to transposition, `W1` and `W2` can also be obtained as *lists* of outer products (of things that can be constructed also by outer products and the `Listable` attribute of `Sin`):

```
u = Sin[KroneckerProduct[xi, m (N[Pi]/a)]].DiagonalMatrix[ SparseArray[m^2]];
v = Sin[KroneckerProduct[yi, n (N[Pi]/b)]];

Max[Abs[Transpose[MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {u, u}], {3, 1, 2}] - W1]]
Max[Abs[Transpose[MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {v, v}], {3, 1, 2}] - W2]]
```

> 7.10543*10^-14
>
> 8.88178*10^-16

From reverse engineering of OP's code (easier said than done), I knew that the result is a linear combination of `W1`, `W2`, `wix`, `wiy`, and the following matrix

```
A = (2 π^4)/a^4 Outer[D11, xi, yi];
```

The latter is basically the array `mat1`, but not flattened out. It was clear that the function `D11` was inefficient, so I compiled it (in a threadable way) into the function `cf`, so that we can obtain `A` also this way

```
A = (2 π^4)/a^4 cf[xi, yi];
```

Next, I looked at the dimensions of these arrays:

```
Dimensions[A]
Dimensions[W1]
Dimensions[W2]
Dimensions[wix]
Dimensions[wiy]
```

> {30, 30}
>
> {10, 10, 30}
>
> {10, 10, 30}
>
> {30}
>
> {30}

So there were only a few possibilities left to `Dot` these things together. So, bearing in mind that `u` and `wix` belong to `xi` and that `v` and `wiy` belong to `yi`,  I guessed this one:

```
intermediateresult = Dot[
   Transpose[MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {u, u}], {3, 1, 2}],
   DiagonalMatrix[wix],
   A,
   DiagonalMatrix[wiy],
   MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {v, v}]
   ];
```

I was pretty sure that all the right numbers were contained already in `intermediateresult`, but probably in the wrong ordering (which can be fixed with `Transpose` later). To check my guess, I computed the relative error of the flattened and *sorted* arrays:

```
(Max[Abs[Sort[Flatten[D11Mat]] - Sort[Flatten[intermediateresult]]]])/Max[Abs[D11Mat]]
```

> 3.71724*10^-16

Bingo. Then I checked the dimensions:

```
Dimensions[intermediateresult]
Dimensions[D11Mat]
```

> {10, 10, 10, 10}
>
> {100, 100}

From the way `D11Mat` was constructed, I was convinced that up to a transposition, `intermediateresult` is just an `ArrayReshap`ed version of `D11Mat`. Being lazy, I just let *Mathematica* try all permutations:

```
Table[
  perm -> 
   Max[Abs[ArrayReshape[
       Transpose[intermediateresult, perm], {dim, dim}] - D11Mat]],
  {perm, Permutations[Range[4]]}
  ]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4} -> 6.01299*10^7, {1, 2, 4, 3} -> 
>     6.01299*10^7, {1, 3, 2, 4} -> 2.23517*10^-8, ...}

Then I just picked the one with the smallest error (which was `{1,3,2,4}`). So our result can be constructed like this:

```
result = ArrayReshape[
   Transpose[
    Dot[
     Transpose[MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {u, u}], {3, 1, 2}],
     DiagonalMatrix[wix],
     A,
     DiagonalMatrix[wiy],
     MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {v, v}]
     ],
    {1, 3, 2, 4}
    ],
   {dim, dim}];
```

Of course, one should confirm this by a couple of randomized tests before one proceeds.

The rest is onky about a couple of local optimizations. Multiplication with `DiagonalMatrix`s can usually replaced by threaded multipication. Know that, I searched for places to stuff the weights `wix` and `wiy` and found this possibility:

```
result = ArrayReshape[
   Transpose[
    Dot[
     Transpose[MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {u, wix u}], {3, 1, 2}],
     A,
     MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {wiy v, v}]
     ],
    {1, 3, 2, 4}
    ],
   {dim, dim}];
```

Then I realized that the first and third factor of the `Dot`-product can be recycled; this is why I stored them in `U` and `V`. Replacing `A` by `(2 π^4)/a^4 cf[xi, yi]` then led to the piece of code above.

## Addendum

Using `MapThread` is actually suboptimal and can be improved by `CompiledFunction`:

```
cg = Compile[{{u, _Real, 1}, {w, _Real}},
   Block[{ui},
    Table[
     ui = w Compile`GetElement[u, i];
     Table[ui Compile`GetElement[u, j], {j, 1, Length[u]}]
     , {i, 1, Length[u]}]
    ]
   ,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

And now

```
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 10}];
w = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000}];
V = w MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {v, v}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
V2 = cg[v, w]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0023
>
> 0.00025

But the `MapThread`s have to be run only once and it is already very fast for the array sizes in the problem. Moreover, for those sizes, `cg` is only twice as fast as `MapThread`.
So there is probably no point in optimizing this out.

Comment: Four orders of magnitude faster it is. I cower in awe.

Comment: @aooiiii No need for that. You made the crucial observation that `mat2` has this low-rank outer product structure; up to transposition, this leads to the factors `U` and `V`. Now one has to know that summation over a low-rank outer product can be sped up significantly by summing _before_ forming the outer product.

Comment: In fact, these days, you don't need to load that package anymore: ``{xi, wix} = Most[NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[nof, MachinePrecision]]``.

Comment: @Henrik, you are the wizard of performance-tuning. Thank you for the code and explanation. You rock, as always!

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. =D You're welcome!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, do you believe still today I'm trying to understand your code? Mainly the transpose parts over the code. =\

Comment: I added a section with the heuristic that I applied to derive the code. It is still a lot about intuition, but at least, I tried to chop things into smaller pieces. 
And one gets better at this each time one solves such a problem.
Maybe it also helps you to see that it is not necessary to fully understand in advance how the code has to be written. 
An efficient implementation does not just fall from heaven. 
Maybe that is obvious but I met many people with that expectation. And it was this expectation that made them think to be bad at programming and thus unhappy.

Comment: Instead, developing code is quite an organic process (for me at least). Often it is already great to have an implementation that does the right thing, no matter how slow it is, because that enables one to just test candidates for more efficient implementations. And hopefully you see in my post: that is just what I did: Educated guessing and thorough testing.

Comment: @Magela, as Henrik notes, it's often useful just to have something that *works* at first, and then worry about optimizing it later (i.e. [incremental development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development)). And as I like to remind, *Mathematica* is often high-level enough that in most cases, you can quickly translate formulae from a textbook/paper into something that works.

Answer (score 12):

I managed to achieve a 20-fold performance boost with the following ideas. First, the elements of your 6-dimensional intermediate array A[m, n, p, q, x, y] can be decomposed into pairwise products of X[m, p, x] and Y[n, q, y] - a square root reduction in trigonometric computations. Then, X and Y can be combined into A via heavily optimized functions `Outer` and `Transpose`.

```
cf = Compile[{{x1, _Real, 1}, {y1, _Real, 1}, {m1, _Real, 
    1}, {n1, _Real, 1}, {p1, _Real, 1}, {q1, _Real, 
    1}, {a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {nof, _Integer}},
  Module[{X, Y},
   X = Table[
     m^2 p^2 Sin[(m \[Pi] x)/a] Sin[(p \[Pi] x)/a],
     {m, m1}, {p, p1}, {x, x1}];
   Y = Table[
     Sin[(n \[Pi] y)/b] Sin[(q \[Pi] y)/b],
     {n, n1}, {q, q1}, {y, y1}];
   Partition[#, nof^2] &@
    Flatten@Transpose[Outer[Times, X, Y], {1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6}]
   ]
  ]

cf[xi, yi, mVec, nVec, mVec, nVec, a, b, nof]; // RepeatedTiming
```

That said, I expect @Roman's DST-based approach to be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: thank you for answering. I really appreciate your approach!